# Can I use my php app to add events in Google Calendar?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to have add/edit/delete events in Google Calendar?
Because all I have accomplished is just to read my events. I`m enabling all the "scopes" I can find about the Calendar API but still I get an error 403 about "Request had insufficient authentication scopes / PERMISSION DENIED".

I have done so many tries to fix that and everytime I get to the same point. I am using OAuth 2.0 Client IDs credentials and one more question I have is which url I should use for the Authorized redirect URIs.

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/*
if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}
*/
/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 10,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => true,
  'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Refer to the PHP quickstart on how to setup the environment:
// https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php
// Change the scope to Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR and delete any stored
// credentials.

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
    array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if (empty($events)) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        if (empty($start)) {
            $start = $event->start->date;
        }
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and include [example] without seeing what you are doing it is not possible for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the event by using your same code with a minor edit. I modified the read-only [scope](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/auth#OAuth2Authorizing) to allow read/write access instead of read-only. This is the final result:

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/*
if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}
*/
/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath))
    {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath) , true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired())
    {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken())
        {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        }
        else
        {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken))
            {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath)))
        {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath) , 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => true,
    'timeMin' => date('c') ,
);
$results = $service
    ->events
    ->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Refer to the PHP quickstart on how to setup the environment:
// https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php
// Change the scope to Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR and delete any stored
// credentials.
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
    'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
    'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
    'start' => array(
        'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
    ) ,
    'end' => array(
        'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
    ) ,
    'recurrence' => array(
        'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
    ) ,
    'attendees' => array(
        array(
            'email' => 'lpage@example.com'
        ) ,
        array(
            'email' => 'sbrin@example.com'
        ) ,
    ) ,
    'reminders' => array(
        'useDefault' => false,
        'overrides' => array(
            array(
                'method' => 'email',
                'minutes' => 24 * 60
            ) ,
            array(
                'method' => 'popup',
                'minutes' => 10
            ) ,
        ) ,
    ) ,
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service
    ->events
    ->insert($calendarId, $event);
printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (empty($events))
{
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
}
else
{
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($events as $event)
    {
        $start = $event
            ->start->dateTime;
        if (empty($start))
        {
            $start = $event
                ->start->date;
        }
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary() , $start);
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

?>
```